# Show that $x=v$ is the only solution to the equation $x+x=2v$ in a vector space. Cite all axioms used

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm not sure how to go about this question... I feel like it is not the only solution so I'm confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it isn't true in characteristic $2$.  Did you leave out some assumptions?

Comment: So start from the axioms, distributive property: $x+x=(1+1)x=2x$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x+x=2x=2v\iff 2x-2v=0\iff2\cdot (x-v)=0\iff x-v=0\iff x=v$$

Comment: Why $2(x-v)=0\Leftrightarrow x-v=0$? Explain please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg the step is $2\cdot (x-v)=0\iff 2=0 \lor x-v=0$

Comment: By which axiom?

Comment: by zero product property which derive by the axioms, do you think that it is not formally correct in such way?

Comment: I think this statement needs a proof, but it's true. See my solution. I think it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course!

It's $$2x=2v$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}(2x)=\frac{1}{2}(2v)$$ or
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\right)x=\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\right)v$$ or
$$1x=1v$$ or
$$x=v.$$